# CJuiAutoComplete is not working in yii

Tags: yii, autocomplete, popupwindow

In my Yii application, CJuiAutoComplete is working on normal page, but not working on popup window. I want to implement this CJuiAutoComplete in popup window. I got the response, but that values are not appended to autocomplete field. My autocomplete codes are below.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
                        'name' => 'inventoryitem_name',
                        'value' => '',
                        'source' => $this->createUrl('inventoryitem/autocompleteInventoryitem'),
                        'options' => array(
                            'showAnim' => 'fold',
                        ),
                        'htmlOptions' => array(
                            'placeholder' => 'Inventory Item',
                            'class' => 'form-control',
                        ),
                        'options' => array(
                            'minLength' => '1',
                            'select' => 'js:function( event, ui ) {
                                 $("#hidden-field").val(ui.item.value);                
                                 return true;  
                                 }',
                        ),
                    ));
                    echo CHtml::hiddenfield('output', '', array('id' => 'hidden-field', 'name' => 'hidden'));
```